# Tab Delimiter in Data Factory

Tags: azure, delimiter, azure-data-factory

I am running into an issue when trying to parse the data from a config file in Data Factory. 
I am using a configuration file and the items are called in the copy activity. We have the option to parameterize the 'Column Delimiter' field from a data set, so I am using the value from the file (because in some cases is ';' and in others '\t'). 
When the delimiter is semicolon is working perfectly, but when it's \t , I get the following error :

> Copy activity doesn't support multi-char or none column delimiter.

When I'm checking the value that goes into the field, I see that the value is not the one from the file (`\t`), but `\\t`.
Do you have any idea why this behavior or if there is an escape character for this one. I also tried with ASCII code (`\0009`) and I get the same error - it doesn't know to transform it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try passing a real tab copied from a text editor, like - '  '.

This has been seen to work. 
Had there been no parameterization in the delimiter, you could have done it through the GUI or even the code.

Comment: is it possible to setup multiple delimiter?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer, is when entering a tab value in the UI, do not use `\t`, instead use `"   "`.
Between the empty quotes, I pasted an actual tab character.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the statements in the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-delimited-text#dataset-properties), Currently, multi-char delimiter is only supported for `mapping data flow` but not `Copy activity`.

[image]

You could try to use `mapping data flows` which is also designed data transformations in ADF. Please see more details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-data-flow-overview

Any concern,please let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the issue is that I'm not dealing with a 'multi-char delimiter'. It's a simple tab delimiter that is working if selected from the Data Factory UI. The question is why when parsing it from a parameter file, the backslash is doubled and therefore seen as a multichar delimiter. (\\t instead of \t)

Comment: is it possible to setup multiple delimiter now?

Answer (score 0):

You should use t instead of \t. Data Factory replaces t with \t itself. That is why \t ends up as \t

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a working solution for this issue. All answers until now didn't work for me.

Click on "Add dynamic content" under the delimiter parameter textbox to open the "Pipeline expression builder".

[image]

Since the tab in base64 is CQ== we can use the following function:

`@base64ToString('CQ==')`

Answer (score 0):

All answers didn't work for me too. In my case, I change the value on the corresponding dataset

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-yHCaqkeJy4

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).