# How to parameterize tab delimiter in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a tab delimited file. I'm able to upload data with static Tab (\t) but when I parametrize it, it doesn't work. I tried all solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58409244/tab-delimiter-in-data-factory), but didn't work for me.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Using the static value `\t` directly in the column delimiter field works for a tab separated file. However, passing this value from the pipeline (as static value) or a parameter with value as `\t` or `'    '` does not work. The following is the sample data that I used

```
id  first_name
1   Rudolfo
2   Pattie
3   Ricki
4   Cora
5   Genni
6   Bonni
7   Wilhelm
8   Chadwick
9   Aeriel
10  Nickie
```

- After giving `\t`  as the value for parameter, you can see how the value is reflected in the pipeline JSON:

[image]

- The output of the look up is also not as expected:

[image]

- So, to achieve this, you can directly change this value as `\t` so that the value will be actually corrected to tab spaces.

[image]

- When I run the pipeline, the result is as expected:

[image]

**UPDATE:**

- Pipeline JSON:

```
{
    "name": "pipeline3",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Lookup1",
                "type": "Lookup",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "policy": {
                    "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                    "retry": 0,
                    "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                    "secureOutput": false,
                    "secureInput": false
                },
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "source": {
                        "type": "DelimitedTextSource",
                        "storeSettings": {
                            "type": "AzureBlobFSReadSettings",
                            "recursive": true,
                            "enablePartitionDiscovery": false
                        },
                        "formatSettings": {
                            "type": "DelimitedTextReadSettings"
                        }
                    },
                    "dataset": {
                        "referenceName": "DelimitedText1",
                        "type": "DatasetReference",
                        "parameters": {
                            "delim": {
                                "value": "@pipeline().parameters.delim",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "firstRowOnly": false
                }
            }
        ],
        "parameters": {
            "delim": {
                "type": "string",
                "defaultValue": "\t"
            }
        },
        "annotations": []
    }
}
```

- Dataset JSON:

```
{
    "name": "DelimitedText1",
    "properties": {
        "linkedServiceName": {
            "referenceName": "AzureDataLakeStorage1",
            "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
        },
        "parameters": {
            "delim": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "DelimitedText",
        "typeProperties": {
            "location": {
                "type": "AzureBlobFSLocation",
                "fileName": "data.csv",
                "fileSystem": "data"
            },
            "columnDelimiter": {
                "value": "@dataset().delim",
                "type": "Expression"
            },
            "escapeChar": "",
            "firstRowAsHeader": true,
            "quoteChar": ""
        },
        "schema": [
            {
                "name": "id\tfirst_name",
                "type": "String"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: This is one case where I definitely prefer the direct code editor because I can easily see the result. Another option that has worked for me is to create a tab in notebook or another text editor, then use copy and paste to set the value in the ADF UI.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't apply same settings. Are you able to share Pipeline and Blob Dataset codes please?

Comment: Hey @Cem, I have added the JSONs.

Comment: Thanks @JoelCochran, i created same but didn't work. I guess will continue with static delimiter value, until figure out.